# Use ddtrace (datadog) with Flask app managed by gunicorn

Tags: flask, gunicorn, datadog

I use gunicorn for my flask application and i want to use Datadog for APM.

I want to configure the ddtrace into the python application but i don't know how fix an application name + envirronnement.

It's ok with the gunicorn exec but i can't specify a name application + env :

```
ExecStart=/bin/ddtrace-run /usr/bin/gunicorn --config /html/app_gunicorn.py -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app
```